# Scala - how to extract a path after an s3:/ prefix with a Regex?

Tags: regex, scala

I want to extract a path starting from a `/bucketName` after the `s3:/` prefix. For now I've managed to extract the `s3:/` prefix itself.

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

val s3Path = "s3://bucketName/dataDir"
val pattern = new Regex("(s3-|s3\\.)?(.*)\\:/")

val pathString: String = (pattern findFirstIn s3Path).getOrElse("")

// prints s3:/
println(pathString)
```

How could I get `/bucketName/dataDir` instead?

Comment: Maybe you need `(?<=s3:/).+`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if I use the suggested pattern, there's just a `/` returned

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong, see https://ideone.com/m0EvlT. I get `/bucketName/data`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow, you are right. When using this like `val pattern = "(?<=s3:/).+".r` it works correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
val pattern = "(?<=s3:/).+".r
val str = "s3://bucketName/data"
println(pattern.findFirstIn(str).getOrElse(""))
```

See the [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/m0EvlT).

**Details**

- `(?<=s3:/).+` - matches a location that is immediately preceded with `s3:/` and then matches any 1+ chars other than line break chars
- `pattern.findFirstIn(str)` - finds the first occurrence of the pattern in the string.

If you want, you may also use pattern matching for this - this way, you do not need a lookbehind, just a capturing group around `.+`:

```
val pattern = "s3:/(.+)".r
val str = "s3://bucketName/data"
val m = str match {
    case pattern(url) => url
    case _ => ""
}
println(s"URL: ${m}") // => URL: /bucketName/data
```

See a [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/BCce86).

One caveat: this requires a full string match.

Answer (score 1):

missing .*

```
 val pattern = new Regex("(s3-|s3\\.)?(.*)\\:/.*")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also match `s3:/` and capture any char except a newline `(.+)` in a group:

```
s3:/(.+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VYWlib/1) | [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/EtZYAs)

```
val s3Path = "s3://bucketName/dataDir"
val pattern = "s3:/(.+)".r
pattern.findFirstMatchIn(s3Path).foreach(m ⇒ println(m.group(1)))
```

Result

```
/bucketName/dataDir
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you also can use String interpolation:

```
val s3Path = "s3://bucketName/dataDir" match {
  case s"s3://$dir" => dir
  case _ => "invalid"
}

println(s3Path)
```